# Microsoft Word formatting options disappearing during edit

Tags: microsoft-office

I'm using Microsoft Office 2016 Pro.

When you double click a word in Microsoft Office, you get a formatting pop up window, just above the text, which gives you quick, basic formatting options to choose from like Bold, Underline, etc.

Right clicking a word\s gives you a more extended list of options.

For the past few days I have a strange thing occurring, where the options disappear after a few seconds and the text blinks a few times. This never happened before.

It's not just with the formatting options but any pop out, like if I open the list of fonts, it will close after a few seconds, even if I am still scrolling the fonts.

It's hard to explain the issue so I recorded the screen so you can see the issue. [Watch here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mn-dROlz6Hg&hd=1)

- I have not installed any programs or Windows\Office updates lately.
- I do NOT have viruses or malware installed. I HAVE restarted my
  machine.
- I used Process Monitor with Filter "Operation is not Process Exit" but didn't see anything.

**UPDATE Sep 2, 2017:**
Found the culprit. Dropbox sync software. With it on, ALL Office products will have this "blink" and make ANY right-click window or pop-out window (like fonts list) disappear every 4 seconds. VERY strange and I will now investigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding Dropbox as the culprit, it was easy to do a Google search on "Dropbox interfering office" and found the solution: In Dropbox preferences, in "Dropbox Badge" choose "Never show". Problem gone.

Answer (score 1):

Boot the computer in Safe mode and check. If the problem disappears, some installed product is to blame, so use
[Autoruns](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)
to disable startup products until you find it.

Otherwise, repair the Office installation as described in the Microsoft article
[Repair an Office application](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Repair-an-Office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b).

Comment: Just closed and reopened and the problem came back.

Comment: Did you test booting in Safe mode?

Comment: I'll do that now. It's not just with the formatting options but any pop out, like if I open the list of fonts, it will close after a few seconds, even if I am still scrolling the fonts. Will update after the safemode test.

Comment: Safe booted with network. Word wouldn't start. Error on opening. Same error when trying to do a repair. Restarted computer to normal mode. Problem is gone. Opened and closed Word a few times - no problem. Maybe just needed a restart after the quick repair.

Comment: Windows sometimes does need a reboot. It's good that the problem is solved.

Comment: Found the culprit. Dropbox sync software. With it on, ALL Office products will have this "blink" and make ANY right-click window or pop-out window (like fonts) disappear every 4 seconds. VERY strange and I will now investigate.